# Examples of web sites using Tridion

Tags: 2013, 2009

I need a list of some web sites that are 'built' using Tridion. Can anybody post a couple of them ? Versions 2009-2013 will do.

Comment: I'd love to see such a list in the community as well, but this isn't something that the community can (completely) answer. SDL and consultants can not mention non-referable customers, whereas customer developers aren't always at liberty to share their details. Knowing something was "Tridion-built" says nothing about implementation details, successes, challenges, or whether it's a fit for your use case. -1 to this as a Tridion.StackExchange question, but +1 to customers willing to help others as references or by sharing. :-)

Comment: I don't think I understand what actual value this would bring. Tridion is a behind-the-scenes technology layer built from the ground-up with the intention to NEVER impose a specific layout or functionality on the delivery side. In theory, if you want to build a site, you can build it with Tridion.

Answer (score 4):

I think just a small google will give you a lots of such authentic results.

You can refer the SDL Tridion website for various customer case studies which will give you have huge list of websites available in SDL Tridion implemented in various SDL Tridion versions.

Below is the link:

[SDL Tridion Case Studies](http://www.sdl.com/resources/wcm-resources-customer-case-studies.html)

Answer (score 3):

This was asked over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640996/examples-of-websites-that-use-sdl-tridion

The list grows every year, perhaps you could be more specific about what you are trying to learn from this question.

Answer (score 1):

http://sdl.com is build with SDL Tridion 2013 (using the [DD4T framework](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/)) and is probably the only site we will be allowed to mention here in full detail, as most customers don't like you to know how they built their site (or specifically with what version), because of security considerations.

Besides that, there are the [case studies](http://www.sdl.com/resources/wcm-resources-customer-case-studies.html) mentioned on the SDL.com website, most of them will relate to the public website of that brand (some provide screenshots which will give you an idea or verification of that fact). Personally one of the nicest examples I find to be http://klm.com (being a long time customer, still using SDL Tridion for their website and currently Media Manager for images and videos).

As Chris mentioned, my biggest question to you is also: Why do you need this info and more specifically, what do you expect to learn from it?